# Binary search tree insertion method doesn't work

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to implement a insertion method for a Binary search tree, and come up with a solution below. I know there are plenty of code examples but I wonder what is the problem in my implementation? Or is there a problem? When I had traced it I thought I have missed something.

```
public void insertBST(Node<Double> head, int value){
   if (head == null){
       head = new Node<Double>(value);
       return;
   }
   else {
       if (head.getValue() > value)
           insertBST(head.getLeft(), value);
       else
           insertBST(head.getRight(), value);
   }
 }
```

Comment: pleas add the `addNode` code to your question so I can help you

Comment: One obvious problem is that if `head` is `null` then you are only assigning the new `Node` to the local `head`, which has no effect outside this function.

Comment: @death7eater: i have updated my answer please check and tell me if you have any other questions.

Comment: Remember to add a language tag to the question. This question is very much language-specific.

Answer (score 2):

When you reassign a passed parameter, you're only changing the local variable, not the value passed to the function. You can read this question for more information - [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) This is Java, right? Either way, a similar argument likely applies.

This is the problem with this line of code:

```
head = new Node<Double>(value);
```

You aren't changing the value passed into the function, so you never add to the tree.

You have two alternatives here, either [the option presented by amdorra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20036476/1711796), or returning the current node:

```
public void insertBST(Node<Double> current, int value)
{
   if (current == null)
   {
       return new Node<Double>(value);
   }
   else
   {
       if (head.getValue() > value)
           head.setLeft(insertBST(head.getLeft(),value));
       else
           head.setRight(insertBST(head.getRight(),value));
       return current;
   }
}
```

To call the function, you can simply say:

```
root = insertBST(root, value);
```

With alternatives, the root will have to be handled as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

at the beginning of you function you are adding the new `Node` to a part you will never have access to outside this function

so i will assume that your Node class looks like the following

```
Class Node{
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    //constructor, setters and getters and stuff
}
```

you could modify your code to look like the following:

```
if (head.getValue() > value){
    if(head.getLeft == null) {
        head.setLeft(new Node<Double>(value));
        return;
    }
    insertBST(head.getLeft(),value);
}
else{
    if(head.getRight == null) {
        head.setRight(new Node<Double>(value));
        return;
    }
    insertBST(head.getRight(),value);
}
```

you should also remove this part `if (head==null)` and always make sure you are sending a valid `Node` to the first call